# Laravel how to combine multiple tables into a view

Tags: php, laravel

I am newish to Laravel, and ran into a pitfall. I have tried to combine 2 tables into the view.

Here is my controller, which references 2 different models.

```
 // Models
use App\Models\Class_DateModel;
use App\Models\CourseModel;

class DataExcelAllController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {


        return view('welcome', [
            'Course' => CourseModel::select('Course_Name')->get(),
            'Class_Date' => Class_DateModel::select('Date', 'End_Date')->get()
        ]);
    }
}

//Initially, I tried to concat the two tables together as such:

<tbody>
            @php
                $i = 0;
                $MergedData = $Course->concat($Class_Date);
            @endphp

            <!-- Class Date -->
            @forelse ($MergedData as $Data1)
                <tr>
                        <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $Data1->Date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $Data1->End_Date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $Data1->Course_Name }}</td>
                </tr>
            @empty

            <!-- What's displayed if empty -->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="14" style="text-align: center">No Records</td>
            </tr>
            @endforelse
        </tbody>
```

But for whatever reason, the Tables are not joined together. To Illustrate, where Key1 is table 1's data and Key 2 is table 2's Data:

Class_DateTable->Key1, Key2, null null

Course_Table->null, null, Key1, Key2

Comment: Are you trying to render the rows from both tables into a single table? If so, you could just use 2 `forelse()` loops and not worry about Type checking. Otherwise, if you're trying to merge the rows from both tables, then you should probably use a SQL-level `join`. Also, manually defining and incrementing `$i` is not necessary; each loop in Laravel has a `$loop` variable, so `@forelse(...) {{ $loop->index }} @endforelse`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: Is there any documentation for using more than one forelse loop at the same time?

Comment: No, but I literally meant `@forelse(...) @endforelse` followed by another `@forelse(...) @endforelse`; as I said, it's a tad unclear what you're trying to do, hence the comment asking for clarification, but it seems you've got an answer, so moot point 